# React Native TextInput not working on mobile browser

Tags: react-native

On desktop with Chrome, login functionality works as intended. When using any web browser on iPhone or Safari on desktop, it will only let me type one letter. There are no errors showing up in the console. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
export const Login: React.FC<{}> = () =>{
const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

function onSubmit()
{
    setLoading(true);

    login(username, password)
        .then(success =>
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                alert("Invalid username or password");
            }
            else
            {
                console.info("Log in successful: " + username);
            }

            setLoading(false);
        });
}

const styles = styleManager.getScope("login");

return (
    <Center>
        

        <TextInput style={styles["username"]} placeholder="Username or Email" autoFocus={true}
            onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} />

        <TextInput style={styles["password"]} placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)} />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles["submitButton"]} onPress={() => onSubmit()}>
            <Text style={styles["submitButtonText"]}>Log In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating={loading} />
    </Center>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the values form your state to the inputs. Maybe you could change your input to:

```
<TextInput style={styles["username"]} placeholder="Username or Email" autoFocus={true} onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} value={username} />

<TextInput style={styles["password"]} placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)} value={password} />
```

All I did here was I add `value` prop to the input fields.
Please, let me know if it solved your problem!